# How to retrieve and print characters from even and odd indexes of a user inputted string in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am new to MIPS coding (beginner) and this is a practice problem I found from my manual.

I tried my best to allocate a heap memory for my user inputted string so that I can loop through the indexes of my string but I am unable to figure out or proceed further.

Can someone explain and guide me on how to *retrieve* and *print* characters from **even** and **odd** indexes of a user inputted string in MIPS using MARS?

I am posting the original question below along with my attempted code.

---

> Write a MIPS program where you prompt the user to enter a string of 16
> characters called `msg`. Then implement the following code using the
> loop given below:
>
> ```c
> for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
>     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
>         print(msg[(i * 2) + j]);    
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> User Input: `"Iamhurtverybadly"`
>
> Output: `"Imuteyalahrvrbdy"`

This is what I wrote till now:

```
        .data
Ask:    .asciiz "Sample Input: \n" 
Answer: .asciiz "Sample Output: \n"

        .text
        li $v0,9  #allocating heap memory
        syscall
        move $s1,$v0
        #print prompt for string,reading and storing string
        li $v0,4
        la $a0,Ask
        syscall
        li $v0, 8 
        la  $a0, 0($s1)
        move $a1,$s0
        syscall
        li $t0,0 #i=0
        li $t1,0 #j=0
        li $t2,2
        li $t3,8
loop:
        lb $t0,0($s1)
        bge $t0,$t2,loop2
        bge $t1,$t3,loop3
        sll $t0,$t0,1
        add $t4,$t0,$t1
        addi $t1,$t1,1
        j loop
loop3:
        addi $t0,$t0,1
        j loop
loop2:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, Answer #display result
        syscall
        li $v0,10
        syscall
```

Comment: Pardon me for the code formatting in the loops

Answer (score 0):

Let's write the C code for your assembly:

```
for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < 2; j++ ) {
    if ( j < 8 ) 
        i++;
    i <<= 1;
    int k = i + j;
}
print("Sample Output: \n");
exit();
```

This isn't going to work, is it?  You have only one loop (yet two loop control variables).  This doesn't follow the model of your original code, which has 2 loops, and they are nested, one fully within the other.  Further, you're modifying the `i` variable by doubling it inside the loop.

---

First, let's review loop translation, step-by-step:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
    ...                              // body of for loop
}
```

---

Change the for loop into while loop:

```
int j = 0;
while ( j < 2 ) {                    // loop top & test
    ...                              // body of loop
    j++;                             // loop control resumes after body
}
```

---

Change the while loop into the if-goto-label style of assembly:

```
    int j = 0;
loop1:                               // loop top
    if ( j >= 2 ) goto loop1Done;    // loop test
    ...                              // body of loop
    j++;                             // loop control
    goto loop1;                      // continue looping
loop1Done:                           // loop done, on to next statement after
```

---

Now, let's do the nested loops:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {      // loop1
    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {  // loop2 (also body of loop1)
        print ( msg [ i*2+j ] );     // body of loop2
    }
}
exit();
```

---

Change the for loops into while loops:

```
int j = 0;
while ( j < 2 ) {
                                     // for loop2 initialization
    int i = 0;                       // <<---- note where i=0 is: inside the outer loop
    while ( i < 8 ) {                // while loop2 top & test
        print ( msg [ i*2+j ] );     // body of loop2
        i++;                         // loop2 control
    }
    j++;                             // loop1 control
}
exit();
```

---

Nested control structures should be translated independently of each other.  If a control structure is nested within another in C, then it should be fully embedded within the translation of the other in assembly language.

Change the while loops into the if-goto-label style of assembly:

```
    int j = 0;
loop1:
    if ( j >= 2 ) goto loop1Done;

                                      // inner for loop2 starts here with initialization
    int i = 0;                        // <<---- note where i=0 is: inside the outer loop

loop2:                                // while loop2 starts here
    if ( i >= 8 ) goto loop2Done;
    print ( msg [ i*2+j ] );          // body of loop2
    i++;                              // loop2 resumes
    goto loop2;
loop2Done:                            // end of loop2

    j++;                              // loop1 resumes
    goto loop1;
loop1Done:                            // end of loop1

    exit();
```

Can you see in the above how the outer loop and the inner loop are related exactly as they are in the C: the inner loop (2) is fully nested within the outer loop (1).

The above can easily be translated into assembly language, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.  Just don't modify `i` or `j` when doing `i*2+j` — compute those into otherwise unused registers.

Comment: Understood. I will try in MARS tool. Thank you Erik!